# How to see where Android permissions come from?

Tags: android, flutter

I searched through my Flutter project, also the plugin directories and tried to find out where the required Android permissions are coming from.
I only found the permission for internet access, which is required by default, in the manifest file of my application:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

However, the following permissions are listed as well when installing the application:

- view network connections
- full network access
- prevent device from
  sleeping

These are considered as [normal permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview.html#normal_permissions), but still I would like to find out where they are coming from because the application does not need these, I believe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The manifest you see in your source is not the one that's in the final APK. The final AndroidManifest gets built up through the build process and compiled from different sources. If you'd like to see a full report of the manifest merging you can go into

```
build/app/outputs/logs
```

This is a very long log report, but you can read where all the manifest parts are coming from. If you'd like to see the final manifest itself this can be found in

```
build/app/intermediates/manifests/full/release or 
build/app/intermediates/manifests/full/debug
```

This won't let you know where it's from, but you can look at the permissions and do a search in your build folder and you should find the partial manifest generated somewhere and you can see where exactly it's coming from.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot just curios. What was adding those permissions?

Answer (score 0):

**=== 2023 UPDATE ===**

You can find now bundle manifest in: `./app/intermediates/bundle_manifest/release/AndroidManifest.xml`